# My guess game just stops after one iteration

Tags: java

My goal was to create a 'guess game' with three "player" objects.

I created a variable known as "target" which contains the input by the user.

After that, I run the "guessing" method on each of the three "player" objects
then I run a while loop which runs until it is broken.
the if statements in the loop check if the guesses of the player objects are equal to the target and breaks the loop if the statement is true.

The problem is that the loop just stops after one iteration.

here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
 class testDrive{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //code 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        player p1 = new player();
        player p2 = new player();
        player p3 = new player();
        System.out.println("Enter p1's name:");
        p1.name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter p2's name:");
        p2.name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter p3's name:");
        p3.name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and 9 for the players to guess");
        int target = sc.nextInt();
        p1.guessing();
        p2.guessing();
        p3.guessing();
        while(true){
            if(target == p1.guess){
                System.out.println(p1.name+" won");
                break;
            }
            else if(target == p2.guess){
                System.out.println(p2.name+" won");
                break; 
            }
            else if(target == p3.guess){
                System.out.println(p3.name+" won");
                break;
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
}}
 class player{
    int guess;
    String name;
    public void guessing(){
        guess =(int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        System.out.println(name+"'s guess is "+guess);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say stops? Does your program end? Or does your program just not do anything?

Comment: Are you sure there was no guessing?

Answer (score 2):

The loop is not ending after 1 iteration. Since we don't have a logger inside the loop it seems as if the execution has stopped. `guessing()` for each player is being called just once before entering the while loop. So each time the same target number is being matched with the already guessed numbers, as a result when there is no match in the first iteration we enter an infinite loop. Move the `guessing()`function for all players inside the while loop so that a new number is guessed during each iteration.

```
Enter p1's name:
p1
Enter p2's name:
p2
Enter p3's name:
p3
Enter a number between 0 and 9 for the players to guess
8
p1's guess is 6
p2's guess is 3
p3's guess is 5
p1's guess is 3
p2's guess is 0
p3's guess is 1
p1's guess is 4
p2's guess is 2
p3's guess is 2
p1's guess is 7
p2's guess is 8
p3's guess is 3
p2 won
```

We would break out of the while loop once we have a match as shown in the above output snapshot.